# Anaconda activate environment command is not working after windows update

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am getting this error -> `\Gow\bin was unexpected at this time` whenever I open my anaconda prompt and also the same error if I try to activate a particular environment. It all started after my recent windows update. I know this a path related problem, I have fixed few after my windows update but this error doesn't make any sense to me. May be there is some quotation related problem, I looked for them in the environment variable path but I couldn't find any such error. Any Idea how can I fix this error?

Thank you so much in advance.

[image]

Comment: Problem solved by updating all the dependencies later. :)